# Closest (plural) descendants

Tags: synonyms

I am working on a programming interface that has functions to give you the closest descendants (in a tree). But there are two categories of function: one gives you exactly one result and the other multiple results.

As a non-native speaker I was hoping for the existence of the word *closests*, so I would not spend so many characters in the function name.

What can I use instead?

Comment: [As per the FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), questions on "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" are off-topic here.

Comment: Aaah sorry for that, I guess the question can be removed then

Comment: @coleopterist  I'd be inclined to waive the ban here, since OP is looking for a semantically appropriate English word to *use* as a name rather than a construction which conforms to programming-language-dependent naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

In another context, a person's "closest descendant" is likely to be his or her ***heir***, which happily is a noun and therefore pluralizable.

Answer (score 0):

*Daughters* is common when talking about trees.  *Children* would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[progeny](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/progeny?view=uk)*

> a descendant or the descendants of a person, animal, or plant; offspring:

This word  is treated as both singular and plural. I am not clear as to whether you need different forms for multiples.